# WSO2SP Streaming processor , load data from MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, wso2, wso2-streaming-integrator

i m trying to load data from mongodb collection.
the collection contains more than 10M documents, and i cannot find any way to limit number of documents to be loaded by SP.

Apparently WsoSO load all document in memory, wisch raised a java out-of-memory error.

Any suggestion please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB will not load all the data to the memory. It will depend on your join query.

```
from TestStream join TestTable
select * 
into Outputstream;
```

Yes, this will load all data, since you have not limited which records to be fetched. Add proper on conditions and it will load only needed records.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Niveathika,

if i execute query directly in mongodb, its work without any problem.

inside WSO2 SP, i added (Limit 1) to limit result.

like bellow :

from TestStream join TestTable
  select *
  **Limit 1**
  into Outputstream;

i havrave Outofmemory errors.

regards.